# How to understand nested subqueries?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to understand subqueries, and I thought I understood the issues I had before, but now I want to understand nested subqueries and now I am even more confused than I was.

I am trying to make an output like this:

```
Model                                Year
---------------------------  ------------
Grand Caravan                        2010
Q70                                  2015
```

The way I af trying to find these are through these descriptions: GPS, Heated Seats, and AWD.

Currently I am getting no rows selected.

My statement is as shown:

```
SELECT t1.MODELNAME AS Model, t2.VEHICLEYEAR AS Year
FROM TBLMODEL t1
FULL JOIN TBLVEHICLE t2 ON t1.MODELID = t2.MODELID
FULL JOIN TBLOPTIONDETAIL t3 ON t2.VEHICLEID = t3.VEHICLEID
FULL JOIN TBLOPTION t4 ON t3.OPTIONID = t4.OPTIONID
WHERE t4.OPTIONDESC IN
(
  SELECT OPTIONDESC
  FROM TBLOPTION
  WHERE OPTIONDESC = 'GPS' AND OPTIONDESC =
  (
    SELECT OPTIONDESC
    FROM TBLOPTION
    WHERE OPTIONDESC = 'Heated Seats'
  )
);
```

The file it corresponds to:

```
DROP TABLE  tblOptionDetail;
DROP TABLE  tblOption;
DROP TABLE  tblVehicle;
DROP TABLE  tblModel;
DROP TABLE  tblBrand;
DROP TABLE  tblManufacture;


CREATE TABLE tblManufacture
(
ManufactureID NUMBER(38) PRIMARY KEY,
ManufactureName CHAR(40)
);

CREATE TABLE tblBrand
(
BrandID NUMBER(38) PRIMARY KEY,
ManufactureID NUMBER(38),
BrandName CHAR(40),
FOREIGN KEY (ManufactureID) REFERENCES tblManufacture(ManufactureID)
);

CREATE TABLE tblModel
(
ModelID NUMBER(38) PRIMARY KEY,
BrandID NUMBER(38),
ModelName CHAR(40),
FOREIGN KEY (BrandID) REFERENCES tblBrand(BrandID)
);

CREATE TABLE tblVehicle
(
VehicleID NUMBER(38) PRIMARY KEY,
ModelID NUMBER(38),
VehicleYear NUMBER(38) CHECK (VehicleYear BETWEEN 1900 and 3000),
VehicleKM NUMBER(38) CHECK (VehicleKM BETWEEN 0 and 100000000),
VehiclePrice NUMBER(38) CONSTRAINT carprice CHECK (VehiclePrice BETWEEN 0 and 1000000),
FOREIGN KEY (ModelID) REFERENCES tblModel(ModelID)
);

CREATE TABLE tblOption
(
OptionID NUMBER(38) PRIMARY KEY,
OptionDesc CHAR(40)
);

CREATE TABLE tblOptionDetail
(
OptionID NUMBER(38),
VehicleID NUMBER(38),
PRIMARY KEY (OptionID, VehicleID),
FOREIGN KEY (OptionID) REFERENCES tblOption(OptionID),
FOREIGN KEY (VehicleID) REFERENCES tblVehicle(VehicleID)
);


-- populate the Manufacture table

INSERT ALL 
INTO tblManufacture (ManufactureID, ManufactureName) VALUES (1,'Chrysler Corp.')
INTO tblManufacture (ManufactureID, ManufactureName) VALUES(2,'General Motors')
INTO tblManufacture (ManufactureID, ManufactureName) VALUES(3,'Ford Motor Company')
INTO tblManufacture (ManufactureID, ManufactureName) VALUES(4,'Toyota')
INTO tblManufacture (ManufactureID, ManufactureName) VALUES (5,'Honda')
INTO tblManufacture (ManufactureID, ManufactureName) VALUES (6,'Nisan')
SELECT * FROM dual;

-- populate the Brand table

INSERT ALL
INTO tblBrand (BrandID, ManufactureID, BrandName) VALUES (1,1, 'Chrysler')
INTO tblBrand (BrandID, ManufactureID, BrandName) VALUES (2,1, 'Dodge')
INTO tblBrand (BrandID, ManufactureID, BrandName) VALUES (3,1, 'Jeep')
INTO tblBrand (BrandID, ManufactureID, BrandName) VALUES (4,2, 'Chevrolet')
INTO tblBrand (BrandID, ManufactureID, BrandName) VALUES (5,2, 'Buick')
INTO tblBrand (BrandID, ManufactureID, BrandName) VALUES (6,2, 'Cadillac')
INTO tblBrand (BrandID, ManufactureID, BrandName) VALUES (7,2, 'GMC')
INTO tblBrand (BrandID, ManufactureID, BrandName) VALUES (8,4, 'Toyota')
INTO tblBrand (BrandID, ManufactureID, BrandName) VALUES (9,6, 'Nissan')
INTO tblBrand (BrandID, ManufactureID, BrandName) VALUES (10,6,'Infiniti')
SELECT * FROM dual;

-- populate the Model table

INSERT ALL
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (1,1, '200')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (2,1, '200 Convertible')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (3,1, '300')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (4,1, 'Town'||' & '||'Country')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (5,2, 'Durango')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (6,2, 'Avenger')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (7,2, 'Challenger')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (8,2, 'Charger')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (9,2, 'Caliber')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (10,2, 'Grand Caravan')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (11,2, 'Journey')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (12,4, 'Sonic')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (13,4, 'Cruze')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (14,4, 'Orlando')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (15,4, 'Colorado')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (16,4, 'Malibu')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (17,8, '4Runner')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (18,8, 'Prius')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES  (19,8, 'Camry')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES  (20,8, 'Corolla')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (21,9,'Rogue SL')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES  (22,9, 'Versa Note')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES  (23,9, 'Pathfinder')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES  (24,9, 'Altima')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES (25,10, 'Q70')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES  (26,10, 'Q50')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES  (27,10, 'Q60')
INTO tblModel (ModelID, BrandID, ModelName) VALUES  (28,10, 'EX37')
SELECT * FROM dual;

-- populate Option table

INSERT ALL 
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (1,'Power locks')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (2,'Power windows')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (3,'Air conditioning')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (4,'Heated mirrors')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (5,'Remote keyless entry')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (6,'CD Player')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (7,'GPS')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (8,'In-dash DVD player')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (9,'Overhead DVD player')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (10,'Satellite radio')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (11,'MP3 player')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (12,'Antilock braking system')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (13,'Electronic stability system')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (14,'Traction control')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (15,'Cruise control')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (16,'Intelligent cruise control')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (17,'Parking assist system')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (18,'Xenon headlights')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (19,'Aluminum rims')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (20,'AWD')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (21,'Convertable')
INTO tblOption (OptionID,OptionDesc) VALUES (22,'Heated Seats')
SELECT * FROM dual;

-- populate Vehicle table

INSERT ALL
INTO tblVehicle (VehicleID,ModelID, VehicleYear, VehicleKM, VehiclePrice) VALUES (1,10, 2010, 45000, 18000)
INTO tblVehicle (VehicleID,ModelID, VehicleYear, VehicleKM, VehiclePrice) VALUES (2,10, 2010, 65420, 17500)
INTO tblVehicle (VehicleID,ModelID, VehicleYear, VehicleKM, VehiclePrice) VALUES (3,16, 2004, 143900, 3200)
INTO tblVehicle (VehicleID,ModelID, VehicleYear, VehicleKM, VehiclePrice) VALUES (4,11, 2010, 38900, 14500)
INTO tblVehicle (VehicleID,ModelID, VehicleYear, VehicleKM, VehiclePrice) VALUES (5,27,2014,17250,45999)
INTO tblVehicle (VehicleID,ModelID, VehicleYear, VehicleKM, VehiclePrice) VALUES (6,25,2015,2900,62300)
INTO tblVehicle (VehicleID,ModelID, VehicleYear, VehicleKM, VehiclePrice) VALUES (7,17,2010,87900,19800)
SELECT * FROM dual;

-- populate OptionDetail table

INSERT ALL
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (2, 2)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (1, 2)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (3, 2)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (5, 2)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (6, 2)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (7, 2)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (8, 2)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (11, 2)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (12, 2)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (14, 2)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (15, 2)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (19, 2)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (2, 1)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (1, 1)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (3, 1)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (6, 1)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (12, 1)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (14, 1)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (15, 1)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (19, 1)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (2, 3)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (1, 3)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (3, 3)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (6, 3)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (12, 3)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (14, 3)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (15, 3)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (19, 3)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (2, 4)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (1, 4)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (3, 4)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (6, 4)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (11, 4)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (12, 4)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (14, 4)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (15, 4)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (19, 4)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES  (4,5)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (8,5)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (1,5)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (2,5)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (5,5)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (21,6)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (22,6)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (3,6)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (1,6)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (2,6)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (1,7)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (4,7)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (5,7)
INTO tblOptionDetail (OptionID, VehicleID) VALUES (2,7)
SELECT * FROM dual;

COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're problem is with this statement

```
WHERE OPTIONDESC = 'GPS' AND OPTIONDESC =
  (
    SELECT OPTIONDESC
    FROM TBLOPTION
    WHERE OPTIONDESC = 'Heated Seats'
  )
```

what this is checking is whether `OPTIONDESC` is equal to 2 different values.. which a single value can never be.. it's like asking

```
WHERE 1 = 1 and 1 = 2
```

you can use `OR` here but not `AND`

if you are trying to get all models have have the two options, you can use GROUP BY with HAVING to COUNT the DISTINCT options.

```
SELECT  t1.MODELNAME AS Model,
        t2.VEHICLEYEAR AS Year
FROM    TBLMODEL t1
        JOIN TBLVEHICLE t2 ON t1.MODELID = t2.MODELID
        JOIN TBLOPTIONDETAIL t3 ON t2.VEHICLEID = t3.VEHICLEID
        JOIN TBLOPTION t4 ON t3.OPTIONID = t4.OPTIONID
WHERE   t4.OPTIONDESC IN ('GPS','Heated Seats')
GROUP BY t1.MODELNAME,
        t2.VEHICLEYEAR
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT t4.OPTIONDESC) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

JamieD77 has given you the answer already. I just want to add some elaboration, because you say you don't understand subqueries and your query shows you are right about this ;-)

```
... AND OPTIONDESC =
  (
    SELECT OPTIONDESC
    FROM TBLOPTION
    WHERE OPTIONDESC = 'Heated Seats'
  )
```

The subquery here selects all records from TBLOPTION with OPTIONDESC = 'Heated Seats'.

Let's say there is exactly one such record. Then you select one row with the value 'Heated Seats', because you select OPTIONDESC, which is 'Heated Seats', the value you were looking for. So the result becomes

```
... AND OPTIONDESC =
    'Heated Seats'
```

Or let's say there is no record with OPTIONDESC = 'Heated Seats'. Then you get

```
... AND OPTIONDESC =
    <nothing>
```

so your condition isn't true and you select no records.

Or let's say there are two or more records with OPTIONDESC = 'Heated Seats'. Then your query crashes, because the DBMS cannot compare a value with an array of values. If there is a unique constraint on OPTIONDESC, then this can not occur. Otherwise you would rather use

```
... AND OPTIONDESC IN (subquery)
```

instead of

```
... AND OPTIONDESC = (subquery)
```